# Gmail in Google Apps now catching too much spam

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, spam-prevention

I just moved from personal gmail to Google Apps gmail. I successfully moved over my label filters and all seemed to be working well. However, I noticed today that many emails that have been correctly labeled are ending up in my Spam folder. None of  these emails are spam, and they used to correctly end up with the right labels (and in the right IMAP folder).

Any tips here? Is there a setting I've overlooked, or maybe it's just a matter of undoing the filters and restarting?

Answer (score 3):

Activate your "Never send it to Spam" option on your filters. It is 3 boxes below the "Apply the Label" check-box.

This will make sure any email that is processed by the filter doesn't end up in the spam folder.

Comment: As usual, an obvious solution that I overlooked. Many many thanks!!